# ImageField Django template

Tags: django

I'm new in Django. I read a lot on documentation and on this site about my question. But I really can not understand what I should do to make this. Can someone show me with all steps please?

**model.py:**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_lengt=50)
    img=models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images')
```

**template:**

```
{% for post in posts %}
     <h1> {{post.title}} </h1>
     <img src="{{post.img}}">
{% endfor %}
```

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

If I access the admin page, how can I upload the image? In template I can't see image!

Sorry for my bad English. Help me please

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `template`, use:

```
{% for post in posts %}
<h1> {{post.title}} </h1>
<img src="{{ post.img.url }}"> 
{% endfor %}
```

You have to add `{{ post.img.url }}`.

Also, make sure that in `urls.py`, you have:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

It will Work.